# Am I able to make such animation in Blender? Which file format to use for output?

Tags: rendering, animation, transparency, file-format

Here is the example of animation. https://youtu.be/6YYgVNy40O8?t=47

0:49. There are 3D golden rings, photo of skyscrapers in it. I am not going to copy one to one this composition.

I want to use another photo on background. And I want to make some abstract figures instead of rings. I will receive animation with alpha channel.

Next step in some video editing software, maybe OpenShot, Shotcut, Kdenlive, DaVinci Resolve I will put animation above junction of two parts of the video.

Am I able to make such animation in Blender? Which file format to use for output?

Comment: We don't know if you are able to make such animations in Blender, but Blender is definitely capable to render them. You don't even need to use any other software for composition.

Comment: You'd probably be able to pull that off by animating a few reflective objects directly in front of the camera with an HDRI background.

Comment: Hi and Welcome Konskoo! Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @metaphor_set Thank you, metaphor_set. So, in this case if I don't need to use any other software for composition I will transfer few videos from camera right to Blender? Yes? In this case Blender will be video editing software? Yes? I will put one after another this few videos, will make animation on the junctions, will make animated captions in the lower third of frame, will edit audio - voice - normalisation of phonogram, highpass and lowpass filtering, equalisation, compression, will add background music, will add sound effects, will make output - the resulting video in Blender? Yes?

Comment: @stphnl329. Thank you, stphnl329. In which file format to import HDRI background to Blender?

Comment: @Konskoo Just lookup free HDRI backgrounds on the web. Those are just HDRI files. I wouldn't recommend doing all the video editing work in Blender if you already know how to use other software, the video editing capabilities in Blender isn't the best. Just render the animation and import that video clip into a video editor that you're familiar with.

Comment: @stphnl329. Thank you, stphnl329. Lets consider the following variant. I will use some video editing software. Maybe OpenShot, Shotcut, Kdenlive, DaVinci Resolve. Mabe some else. What to use to transfer animation from Blender to video editing software? To use video or sequence of images?

Comment: I'd recommend using an image sequence. Many video editing Softwares have the built in capability to import an image sequence to a video. Image sequences also have the added benefit of allowing you to not lose all the render progress if something goes wrong halfway through

Comment: @stphnl329. Thank you, stphnl329. For such kind of animation with 3D abstract figures, background image, transparency on left and right borders which file format for images to use? It will be image sequence. What will be the file format of every image?

Comment: I don't think you'd need transparency. If the video editor supports masking, the whole video transition effect can be doine with that. Since it's a short animation, PNG files will work just fine.

Comment: @stphnl329. Thank you, stphnl329. I took in attention your variant with masking. You wrote "You'd probably be able to pull that off by animating a few reflective objects directly in front of the camera with an HDRI background". Will I be able to transfer animation with HDRI background from Blender to video editing software using PNG image sequence?

Comment: What you're going to achieve with Blender is a short video clip in the form of a PNG image sequence. Then to use it as a transition, you just need to animate/overlay that short video clip in front of the videos that you want to transition from using the video editing software of your choice.

Comment: @stphnl329. Thank you, stphnl329. I took in attention. What if I will transfer animation from Blender not directly to video editing software but firstly to Natron to make VFX? And then from Natron I will transfer animation to video editing software. In this case in Blender in output I should use OpenEXR Multylayer and during render I should make few render passes. Yes?

Comment: Yeah, that will work. I'm not too familiar with all the software you mentioned, but the multilayer part sounds like the type of thing you'll need to do

Comment: @stphnl329. Thank you, stphnl329. When people use HDRI backgrounds in Blender how they see the result of their work? They use some special monitors?

Comment: There is a rendered preview mode in Blender that'll let you preview the render results without having to actually wait for the long renders

Comment: @stphnl329. Thank you, stphnl329. Monitor has 8 bit per channel. It is 24 BitsPerPixel. 16,7 Million color variations. How people see HDRI backgrounds in Blender using such monitors? Or they use some other monitors which have more than 8 bit per channel?

Comment: You're going to be exporting a short video clip from Blender which you can then manipulate in video editing software to use as a transition.